# How to configure sent to me filter in Gmail that it doesn't includes chat messages?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I have set up a filter for mails sent to my email address in Gmail, This being most important I need to keep an eye on the mails getting collected under this label.

Now we guys in office also use Gmail hangout, the messages from hangout also shows up in this sent to me labeled filter.

Does anyone know how to setup sent to me filter?

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: @Rubén what do you expect to see in the brief description ?

Comment: You could include what related questions from this sit you found and why they doesn't help you.